# Finding path to SD card in Android web-app

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-sdcard

I'm developing an Android "in-browser" app using Cordova (AKA Phonegap), running on the device itself. I have no problem reading/writing files to the SD card in my emulator, but it occurs to me that I can't rely on it being mounted at /sdcard in the real world, especially since a friend pointed out that some devices may actually have more than one.

Having hunted around, I can see plenty of answers as to how to find the path to the SD card when developing an app in Java, but no mention of how to do the same thing inside my Javascript. I wonder if anybody might be able to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

That's why you use:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
```

The file system object you get in the onSuccess callback will have a root property which is a DirectoryEntry which points to, in most cases, the /sdcard directory on Android. This method calls Java code to determine the proper external storage directory and it should be consistent for you.

Comment: Thanks. My original code was almost right, but this should make it more robust.

Comment: The bad news is, this isn't consistent. It seems to correctly get the path to /mnt/sdcard, but unfortunately some devices have a different path to the card, which it doesn't resolve. (one particular user has a Samsung Galaxy S3 where the removable card is mounted as extSD. But the filesystem request still goes to sdcard.

Comment: Then that is a bug on that phone as it doesn't return the correct value for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() which is the Android API call we use to figure out where the storage is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to save photos using PhoneGap, you should use the property:

```
destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, saveToPhotoAlbum: true
```

The images saved in this path: / mnt / sdcard / DCIM / camera

The complete code looks like this:

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
```